# Using Cairo on iPhone?

Tags: c++, iphone, cairo

I'm doing some work on a potentially cross-platform C++ application and for Windows and OS X it seems that Cairo will meet most of my needs for 2D graphics and allow me to share a lot of code between platforms.  In an ideal world I'd really like to be able to use the same (or very similar) drawing code in iPhone/iPad apps.

I realise that this means that I'll need to compile Cairo for iPhone before I try to use it, but I've got no real idea on how to go about this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: http://cplus.about.com/b/2008/11/07/cairo-graphics-open-source-2d-rendering.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update this for anyone who happens to try going down the same route as I did, I never did get it to compile (I didn't get much response from the Cairo mailing list when I asked for suggestions). It seems that Cairo isn't really a very good idea for iOS or OSX. I've recently come across [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.cairo/22494) post which pretty clearly says that it's not stable on iOS or OSX.

I'm now quite glad that I made the decision to ditch Cairo as my cross-platform graphics method and go to a home-brew/native method. Although it involves a bit more effort, it's been a pretty good compromise for what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean with "not stable"? That post says that some minor changes where needed to make this work on iOS and asks for those few changes to be merged upstream. After these few changes, everything seemed to work fine for him on iOS. And he doesn't even mention OSX...

Comment: I was referring to the section where it says "I'm trying to use my cairo-time to fix quartz... as you might have noticed 1.12 shipped with multiple crashes in the test suite". As he said he hadn't installed the iOS SDK I assumed he meant that the crashes were in Quartz on OSX. As far as I can see in the current 1.12.2 release notes (http://cairographics.org/news/cairo-1.12.2/) there are no updates to Quartz so I assume this is still unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I've compiled Cairo using Visual Studio like this:

- libpng-1.2.40
- zlib-1.2.3
- pixman-0.16.2
- cairo-1.8.8

Since Cairo will be using Quartz for font and text handling you will not have to compile Pango (which has Glib as dependency) and FreeType. I assume the setup for iPhone should be similar.

[This](http://blog.vlad1.com/2008/03/16/cairo-16-quartz-and-gecko/) entry from Vladimir Vukićević's blog shows that Cairo runs on iPhone since 2008 :)